# Show only email+ (Any specific app) as shareable option in UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller

Is there any way by which we can get rid of all default sharing options provided by UIActivityViewController and display only specific apps (in my case Email+) as sharing medium.

Comment: Have you read the documentation for `excludedActivityTypes`?

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. So what happens in the situation when user installs a new app which was not excluded explicitly. Dont you think such apps will start appearing.

Comment: The whole point of `UIActivityViewController` is to let the user decide what to do with the file/text/image/whatever. If you want complete control over the options, don't use `UIActivityViewController`.

Comment: Okay, it may be worng approach in this case then. Any suggestion as alternative?

Comment: You can try to open the app directly using their URL scheme, `mailto:address@domain.com`. Or detect if the device has some apps and present an action sheet with options. That what people often do with maps, checking if the device can open the URL `comgooglemaps://` to present an option to open something on Google Maps app.